# Iterate a particular code in for loop only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, for-loop

After several tries finally I am here..Trust I will get a possible solution..

Here is my code:

```
var sections=[];

sections.push({
    questions:questions
});

for(var q1  in questions1){
    if (questions1[q1].fieldtype == "checkbox") {
        var options=questions1[q1].mcoptions;
        for(var i=0;i < options.length;i++)
        {
            for(var c=0; c < checkedValues.length; c++)
            {
                if(options[i].value == checkedValues[c])
                {
                    questions.push({
                        seqNum : questions1[q1].seqNum, 
                        qtext : questions1[q1].qtext, 
                        qimage : questions1[q1].qimage,
                        fieldtype : questions1[q1].fieldtype,
                        mcoptions : mcoptions
                    });

                    mcoptions.push({
                        value : options[i].value,
                        greyOut : greyOut,
                    }); 

                    var grey=options[i].greyOut;
                    for(var g=0;g<grey.length;g++)
                    {
                        greyOut.push({
                            greyOut  : grey[g]
                        });
                    }
                }}
        }// for loop close
    }//fieldtype
}// q1 in questions
```

This code will perform GET request from API,compare checkbox value and post in another API in JSON format.

Question 1) After comparing if(options[i].value == checkedValues[c]) , I want

```
           questions.push({
                seqNum : questions1[q1].seqNum, 
                qtext : questions1[q1].qtext, 
                qimage : questions1[q1].qimage,
                fieldtype : questions1[q1].fieldtype,
                mcoptions : mcoptions
            });
```

to display only once which is in for loop. mCoptions. push and grey should iterate other values in for loop and display under questions[]. Now the whole structure iterates based of checkedValues which shouldn't be the case.

Question 2) After greyOut : greyOut in mcoptions.push, I want to fetch and add another one item from API which has dynamic key and value. Like mcoptions[value: value, greyOut:grey[g] , x: 1]

Question 3) If I go to the same section and change my answer and click submit(POST request), I want sections[0] to be removed and replaced entirely.

Please help and share your valuable suggestions.. Thank you so much in advance.

JSON format:

```
[{
    "sessionName": "XYZ",
    "ID": "123",
    "sections": [{
        "slabel": "Development",
        "qlabel": "text",
        "questions": [{
            "seqNum": "1",
            "qtext": "What level of understanding would you say there is of Dev principles and methods?",
            "qimage": "",
            "fieldtype": "checkbox",
            "mcoptions": [{
                "value": "none",
                "greyOut": [
                    "1.1",
                    "1.2"
                ],
                "dev": "0"
            }, {
                "value": "some",
                "greyOut": [],
                "cog": "10"
            }, ]
        }]
    }, {
        "slabel": "Development111",
        "qlabel": "text",
        "questions": [{
            "seqNum": "1",
            "qtext": "What level of understanding would you say there is of Dev principles and methods?",
            "qimage": "",
            "fieldtype": "checkbox",
            "mcoptions": [{
                "value": "none",
                "greyOut": [
                    "1.1",
                    "1.2"
                ],
                "dev": "0"
            }, {
                "value": "some",
                "greyOut": [],
                "cog": "10"
            }, ]
        }]
    }]

}]
```

Comment: What API? Third-party API?

Comment: If you format your code, you'll not need these annotations, wich bracket closes wich loop, and it's easier to read/understand, even for you. Then, `mcoptions` and `greyOut`, are you sure you want to mutate these Arrays *(Array.push)*? Because this also mutates all references you've added to previous questions. and last, I don't understand your questions, because I don't know what your app looks like, what it's intended to do, what parts misbehave, ... , basically I'm not in your head. I need more info, about what your code should do, what it does, what it doesn't and what's wrong about that.

Comment: @zer00ne - Yes, It is a third party API(URL) where I will stringify and post the JSON data and get the value in turn

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Javascript allows you to put `,` after the last element of an array, but JSON doesn't.

Comment: @Thomas - I understand your point. Please find my edited version with the JSON added. I hope now you would be able to identify the code. I get the value from this JSON, compare the checked values by user in UI and post the respective JSON values in same structure to another URL. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar - Sorry that I made a manual typo error there. My actual JSON works fine and throws the required output except the questions where I am stuck up with..

Answer (score 0):

1) You can test whether `questions` already has something in it before pushing a new item to it:

```
if (questions.length == 0) {
    questions.push({
        seqNum : questions1[q1].seqNum, 
        qtext : questions1[q1].qtext, 
        qimage : questions1[q1].qimage,
        fieldtype : questions1[q1].fieldtype,
        mcoptions : mcoptions
    });
}
```

2) Perform the API request, and in the callback add the additional property to the `mcoptions` value. You can use an IIFE to make a closure to hold a reference to the object that needs to be updated in the callback.

```
var newmcoption = {
    value : options[i].value,
    greyOut : greyOut,
};
mcoptions.push(newmcoption);
(function(mcoption) {
    CallAPI(function(response) {
        mcoption.x = response;
    });
})(newmcoption);
```

3) I'm not really sure I understand this part of the question, but I think you can do:

```
sections.length = 0;
sections.push({
    questions:questions
});
```

to clear out the previous data and start fresh.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually questions[ ] holds multiple values under that. So I cannot use questions.length == 0. Rather like questions[0],etc.. Could you please correct where I can implement the indexing like questions[q1].push..

Comment: I found your question very confusing, but I did my best to try to understand it. Maybe it should be `if (questions[q1].length == 0) { questions[q1].push(...); }`